# writing the javascript to use a search bar to open and search details tags and open and search summary tags

Tags: full-text-search

I have the search bar working, but it doesn't open the details or summary tags.

This is the html and javascript that I am using:

```
<body>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="search-input" placeholder="Search.....">
        </div>

        <div class="accordion-container">
            <div class="accordion-ipr">
                <h1 id="description">Poker Rules</h1>
                <div>
                    <details>
                        <summary class="dropdown1" >
                            "SECTION I: TOURNAMENT GUIDELINES"
                        </summary>
                            <details VENUES>
                                <summary id="dd2" >
                                    <p id="dropdown2"> 1. VENUES </p> 
                                </summary>
                                <div class="gallery">   
                                    <div>
                                        <p id="indent20"><b>1.</b> Venues should provide a player-friendly environment.
                                            The following should be provided and/or posted in a manner that is clearly visible within the 
                                            tournament area:
                                            <br>
                                        </p>
                                    </div> 
                                </div>
                            </details> 

                            <details MANAGEMENT>
                                <summary id="dd2">
                                    <p id="dropdown2"> 2. MANAGEMENT  </p> 
                                </summary>
                                <div class="gallery">     
                                    <div>
                                        <p id="indent20"><b>1.</b> Management will attempt to maintain a pleasant environment for their customers and employees, but 
                                            is not responsible for the conduct of any player. Management reserves the right to refuse any player 
                                            entry into the casino, card room, and/or tournament area(s).
                                            <br>
                                        </p>  
                                    </div> 
                                </div>
                            </details> 

                            <details TOURNAMENT DIRECTORS>
                                <summary id="dd2">
                                    <p id="dropdown2"> 3. TOURNAMENT DIRECTORS  </p> 
                                </summary>
                                <div class="gallery">      
                                    <div>
                                        <p id="indent20">
                                            <b>1.</b> Tournament Directors are to control the progress of the tournament and are to consider the technical 
                                            rules for the best interest of the tournament, the game, and its players. 
                                        </p>  
                                    </div> 
                                </div>
                            </details>

                            <details FLOOR PEOPLE>
                                <summary id="dd2">
                                    <p id="dropdown2"> 4. FLOOR PEOPLE  </p> 
                                </summary>
                                <div class="gallery">     
                                    <div>
                                        <p id="indent20">
                                            <b>1.</b> Floor People are to provide supervision and are to consider the technical rules for the best interest of 
                                            the game and its players. 
                                            <br>
                                        </p>  
                                    </div> 
                                </div>
                            </details>

                            <details DEALERS>
                                <summary id="dd2">
                                    <p id="dropdown2"> 5. DEALERS  </p> 
                                </summary>
                                <div class="gallery">        
                                    <div>
                                        <p id="indent20">
                                            <b>1.</b> Dealers are to control the progress of the game. 
                                            <br>
                                            Their role is to state the action and facilitate the progress of a fair game; as to the technical rules, 
                                            dealers should act in a fair manner and must remain neutral to all players.
                                        </p> 
                                    </div> 
                                </div>
                            </details>
                    </details>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>

            $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#search-input').on('keyup', function() {
                var searchText = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
                $('.accordion-container .accordion-ipr').each(function() {
                var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
                var words = text.split(/\W+/); // split into words
                var accordion = $(this);
                var match = false;
                words.forEach(function(word) {
                    if (word.indexOf(searchText) === 0) {
                    match = true;
                    }
                });
                if (match) {
                    accordion.show();
                } else {
                    accordion.hide();
                }
                });
            });
            });

        </script>

    </body>
```

How do I get the details tags or the summary tags to open if a word that is typed into the search bar is inside any of these elements?

Also how do I get any word that is typed into the search bar to be highlighted in yellow wherever they appear in the document?